# display all Files in Folder and Subfolder in listWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

I want to display all *.dat files which are in a selected path including the subfolder: my selected folder is "C:\iba\dat" and in iba there are two other folders Energie and Prozess and in these two folders are my Files which I want to display in my ListWidget.

```
FAeingabe::FAeingabe(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::FAeingabe)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //icon
    setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/Icons/icon.ico"));

    QDir myPath("C:\\iba\\dat");
    QStringList nameFilters;
    nameFilters<<"*.dat";
    myPath.setFilter(QDir::AllEntries | QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::NoDot);
    faList = myPath.entryList();
    ui->listWidget->addItems(faList);
    ui->total->setText(QString("%1").arg(ui->listWidget->count()));
}
```

I get this:
[image]

Comment: For recursive listing of files, you can use `QDirIterator` with the `Subdirectories` flag.

Comment: yes you right. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you have not used your nameFilters. Second, you should use QDirIterator for getting the list of files.

```
QDirIterator it(QStringLiteral("C:\\iba\\dat"), QStringList() << "*.dat", QDir::Files, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
QStringList faList;
while (it.hasNext())
       faList.append(it.next());
```

Comment: it works thank you.
it displays now all files but with full path which is not disturbing me. is it possible to display just the file name without the path?

Comment: Just add one more variable type QFileInfo, and getting the file name from it:

while (it.hasNext()) {
            QFileInfo file(it.next());
                faList.append(file.fileName());
            }